# Is there a way to check for int easily?

Tags: c#

Is there a simple expression I could put into an if statement to check if a value is an int? 
Something like this, to check if `x` is an int:

```
x = 1

if (Diceroll() = 1)
{
    x = x * 0.75
}
if (Diceroll() = 2)
{
    x = x * 1.25
}
if (Diceroll() = 3)
{
    x = x * 1
}


if (x != int)
{
    consol.writeline("X is not an int")
}
if (x = int)
{
    consol.writeline("X is an int")
}
```

Comment: Well what's the type of `x` to start with? Please give a [mcve]... we can't really tell what you're trying to achieve at the moment.

Comment: Your code won't compile as it.

Comment: @ja72 I don't think you need this code to compile to see what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I was referring to `consol` and `writeline` which are syntactically incorrect for no reason.

Comment: I suggest you edit your title to something like "Is there a way to check if a decimal number is really an integer".

Comment: @ja72 You know you can edit posts yourself, right?

Comment: Yes but how is this going to help the OP? It would be more helpful if their title matched what they were asking for more closely.

Comment: When looking for the solution to a problem, you need to utilize the proper terminology. When we take your question literally, it is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/: `bool isInt = value is int;`. But that shows literally whether the value is an int, which is not what you seem to be looking for. Assuming that `x` is a floating-point number like `float` or `double`, the above check will never be true. Instead, your actual question is "how to check if a float contains an integer number", and that's been answered before in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142252/.

Comment: Does `Diceroll()` have different results on each call? What if it returns 1, 2, 3 - x is multiplied by 1.25 and 0.75 and 1!

Answer (score 4):

You can write something like this:

```
double x;

// your code here

if (x != Math.Floor(x))
   Console.WriteLine("X is not an int")
else
   Console.WriteLine("X is an int")
```

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650120/3901618 about comparing floating point values (according to CodeCaster's comment).

Comment: Judging by the little information we have this is probably what OP was really looking for. Just have to be aware of rounding errors. Using a little epsilon value for a fuzzy comparison might be enough, but personally I'd avoid using floating point if possible.

Comment: Or simply x % 1 == 0, if doubles are his use case

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify your question a little. First of all, what is the type of x - object?

Second, do you want to strictly test if its data type is int?
That would be easy:

```
 object p = ....;
 bool is_int = p is int;
```

Or you want to check for addition things? For example...

- ... the above would fail if p is an Int64, or An Uint32, etc. or
  basically any other integer type which isn't strictly int (Int32)
- The above would also fail is for double p = 1.
- ... And it would also
  fail for string p = "1"

These are cases you may or may not want to consider? If so, they need additional work.

Comment: `is` works for reference types only.

Comment: Hmm don't think so?  bool is_int1 = ((int)1) is int; bool is_int2 = ((double)2) is int;  compiles fine and works as expected

Comment: I've always used `is` together with `as` which is definitely only for ref types.

Comment: Yep, "as" only works with ref types. Everything else wouldn't make a lot of sense indeed; e.g. int number = somevariable as int;   what should this return if somevariable wasn't int? default(int), so 0? That'd be indistinguishable from a a case where int somevariable = 0. Anyways, that's not an issue for the "is" keyword tho as that doesn't struggle with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different interpretations of your question, if you're asking if the value of "x" can be an integer, you use.

```
int temp = 0;
string x = "numberofsomesort";
if (!int.TryParse(x,out temp))
{
    Console.Writeline("X is not an int");
}
```

Or if you have an object and you want to check its type, you use.

```
object x;

if (!(x is int))
{
    Console.Writeline("X is not an int");
}
```

EDIT: Looking at your new code, the first suggestion is the correct one as you're checking to see if the value of "x" can be converted into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

```
int aIntValue;
if(int.TryParse(x, out aIntValue))
```

If int.TryParse returns true, it will convert the value 'x' to the varible "aIntValue'. If return false, the 'x' isn't a number.

Or you can do this:

```
if(!(x is int))
```

Comment: Identical to my answer

Comment: Sorry, you posted a couple secods before me, I didn't saw. You don't need to negativate me just for this.